# Tesseract OCR not working in Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract OCR in a web application. The code runs fine when I run it as a JAVA application. But as soon as I put the same code in my web application, it doesn't work anymore. If put the function in the servlet, tomcat doesnt start at all. If I call it from a separate class by creating an object, On debugging I find that the object does not get created at all. I have included all the jars necessary.

Code in servlet

```
OCRFullTrial ot = new OCRFullTrial();
ot.imgOCR();
```

Inside other class

```
public void imgOCR(){
    File imageFile = new File("D:\\OCRTesting\\0.jpg");

try {
     ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();  //            
    System.out.println("1");

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some pointers I think you should check, in case if you are using Tess4j in Web Based Project:

1. Put all your jars in WEB-INF > lib folder.
2. The *.dll files that are provided along Tess4j must be in system32 folder (Windows). I don't know for other OS.
3. Set the instance path using `instance.setDataPath()` method. It must point to folder containing tessdata folder.
4. Set the language using `instance.setLanguage()` in case your tessdata has multiple languages training data in them.

Crosscheck above steps and try running again.

Comment: I am also trying to get a webservice up to be hosted on an apache server.
I am using apache tika and in the API it says I just need to reference the folder for tesseract like this
TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
config.setTesseractPath(tesseractFolder);

What do i place in the folder ( tesseract jar files?) and what path should i use, if I use WEB-INF for example how should it start "/WEB-INF/tesseract/JarFileINeedToSpecifyPath.jar"?